# How to join two dataframes and leave blank items not found?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

In python3 and pandas I have these two dataframes

```
candidatos_2018.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8583 entries, 5 to 404
Data columns (total 11 columns):
uf                 8583 non-null object
cargo              8583 non-null object
sequencial         8583 non-null object
numero_urna        8583 non-null object
nome_completo      8583 non-null object
nome_urna          8583 non-null object
cpf                8583 non-null object
e_mail             8583 non-null object
partido_eleicao    8583 non-null object
data_nascimento    8583 non-null object
ocupacao           8583 non-null object
dtypes: object(11)
memory usage: 804.7+ KB

total.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 5534 entries, 3277 to 5111
Data columns (total 2 columns):
sequencial    5534 non-null object
total_bens    5534 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 129.7+ KB
```

Dataframes have a common key, the "sequencial" column. But the dataframe "candidatos_2018" has more rows than the dataframe "total"

I want to merge the two dataframes, so that all "candidatos_2018" lines are retained, even when their key does not exist in "total" - in those cases the column "total_bens" may appear blank on the respective line

Please, does anyone know how I can do it?

I want the result to be a dataframe of 8,583 rows, with all columns of "candidatos_2018" plus the columns of "total"

If I make a simple merge:

```
teste =  pd.merge(candidatos_2018, total, left_on='sequencial', right_on='sequencial')
```

The result is smaller dataframe, only with the "sequencia" keys found in the two dataframes

I want to keep all the lines "candidatos_2018" and when the key does not exist in "total" leave this line blank in the "total_bens" column

-/-

Sample dataframes content

```
candidatos_2018.head(2).to_dict()
{'uf': {5: 'AC', 6: 'AC'},
 'cargo': {5: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL', 6: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL'},
 'sequencial': {5: '10000600207', 6: '10000602510'},
 'numero_urna': {5: '1712', 6: '2222'},
 'nome_completo': {5: 'DANIELA PAIVA DE OLIVEIRA',
  6: 'ANTÔNIA LUCILÉIA CRUZ RAMOS CÂMARA'},
 'nome_urna': {5: 'DANIELA PAIVA', 6: 'ANTÔNIA LÚCIA'},
 'cpf': {5: '52614174220', 6: '50791524272'},
 'e_mail': {5: 'PSL17.AC@GMAIL.COM', 6: 'ANTONIALUCIACAMARAPR22@GMAIL.COM'},
 'partido_eleicao': {5: 'PSL', 6: 'PR'},
 'data_nascimento': {5: '23/12/1982', 6: '17/07/1970'},
 'ocupacao': {5: 'OUTROS', 6: 'EMPRESÁRIO'}}

total.head(2).to_dict()
{'sequencial': {3277: '250000600423', 3279: '250000600426'},
 'total_bens': {3277: 1202006700.0, 3279: 1018384000.0}}
```

Assuming that in the example, from the dataframe "candidatos_2018", the key "10000600207" exists in both dataframes and the key "10000602510" only exists in the dataframe "candidatos_2018". The result of the union will be

```
{'uf': {5: 'AC', 6: 'AC'},
 'cargo': {5: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL', 6: 'DEPUTADO FEDERAL'},
 'sequencial': {5: '10000600207', 6: '10000602510'},
 'numero_urna': {5: '1712', 6: '2222'},
 'nome_completo': {5: 'DANIELA PAIVA DE OLIVEIRA',
  6: 'ANTÔNIA LUCILÉIA CRUZ RAMOS CÂMARA'},
 'nome_urna': {5: 'DANIELA PAIVA', 6: 'ANTÔNIA LÚCIA'},
 'cpf': {5: '52614174220', 6: '50791524272'},
 'e_mail': {5: 'PSL17.AC@GMAIL.COM', 6: 'ANTONIALUCIACAMARAPR22@GMAIL.COM'},
 'partido_eleicao': {5: 'PSL', 6: 'PR'},
 'data_nascimento': {5: '23/12/1982', 6: '17/07/1970'},
 'ocupacao': {5: 'OUTROS', 6: 'EMPRESÁRIO'},
 'total_bens': {5: 1202006700.0, 6: null}}
```

Comment: Try doing merge?

Comment: Yes (test = pd.merge (candidates_2018, total, left_on = 'sequential', right_on = 'sequential')

Comment: Please make a small, minimal example. Two sample dataframes and the result you expect.

Comment: But so it discards lines that "candidatos_2018" have no code "sequencial" in "total"

Comment: Thanks, put it up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `how='left'`, like this:

```
pd.merge(candidatos_2018, total, how='left', left_on='sequencial', right_on='sequencial')
```